# Display subtitles while playing mp3 audio

Tags: ios, metadata, core-audio

I need to build an app which will highlight a word in String as the audio is played. I need this to be done in sync with the sound. The audio is not continuos. e.g for "Hello, how are you ?" there can be a delay between "Hello" and "How".
 I checked MIDI file format but it can hold musical notes only, where my mp3 has speech.
The last option I see is to maintain a file with start time of a word in audio and highlight it while displaying. 
Can anybody suggest better option ?

Answer (score 0):

ID3 tags support the `SYLT` or synchronized lyrics frame.  From http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames:

> 4.9.   Synchronised lyrics/text
>
> This is another way of incorporating the words, said or sung
>   lyrics,    in the audio file as text, this time, however, in sync with
>   the    audio. It might also be used to describing events e.g.
>   occurring on a    stage or on the screen in sync with the audio. The
>   header includes a    content descriptor, represented with as
>   terminated text string. If no    descriptor is entered, 'Content
>   descriptor' is $00 (00) only.
>
> ```
>  <Header for 'Synchronised lyrics/text', ID: "SYLT">
>  Text encoding        $xx
>  Language             $xx xx xx
>  Time stamp format    $xx
>  Content type         $xx
>  Content descriptor   <text string according to encoding> $00 (00)
> ```
>
> Content type:   $00 is other
>                      $01 is lyrics
>                      $02 is text transcription
>                      $03 is movement/part name (e.g. "Adagio")
>                      $04 is events (e.g. "Don Quijote enters the stage")
>                      $05 is chord (e.g. "Bb F Fsus")
>                      $06 is trivia/'pop up' information
>                      $07 is URLs to webpages
>                      $08 is URLs to images
>
> Time stamp format:
>
> ```
>  $01  Absolute time, 32 bit sized, using MPEG [MPEG] frames as unit
>  $02  Absolute time, 32 bit sized, using milliseconds as unit
> ```
>
> Absolute time means that every stamp contains the time from the
>   beginning of the file.
>
> The text that follows the frame header differs from that of the
>   unsynchronised lyrics/text transcription in one major way. Each
>   syllable (or whatever size of text is considered to be convenient by
>   the encoder) is a null terminated string followed by a time stamp
>   denoting where in the sound file it belongs. Each sync thus has the
>   following structure:
>
> ```
>  Terminated text to be synced (typically a syllable)
>  Sync identifier (terminator to above string)   $00 (00)
>  Time stamp                                     $xx (xx ...)
> ```
>
> The 'time stamp' is set to zero or the whole sync is omitted if
>   located directly at the beginning of the sound. All time stamps
>   should be sorted in chronological order. The sync can be considered
>   as a validator of the subsequent string.
>
> Newline characters are allowed in all "SYLT" frames and MUST be
>   used    after every entry (name, event etc.) in a frame with the
>   content type    $03 - $04.
>
> A few considerations regarding whitespace characters: Whitespace
>   separating words should mark the beginning of a new word, thus
>   occurring in front of the first syllable of a new word. This is also
>   valid for new line characters. A syllable followed by a comma should
>   not be broken apart with a sync (both the syllable and the comma
>   should be before the sync).
>
> An example: The "USLT" passage
>
> ```
>  "Strangers in the night" $0A "Exchanging glances"
> ```
>
> would be "SYLT" encoded as:
>
> ```
>  "Strang" $00 xx xx "ers" $00 xx xx " in" $00 xx xx " the" $00 xx xx
>  " night" $00 xx xx 0A "Ex" $00 xx xx "chang" $00 xx xx "ing" $00 xx
>  xx "glan" $00 xx xx "ces" $00 xx xx
> ```
>
> There may be more than one "SYLT" frame in each tag, but only one
>   with the same language and content descriptor.

and as of a few days ago the master branch of `taglib` (https://github.com/taglib/taglib) supports `SYLT` frames.  You could use taglib to extract the synchronized lyrics for your display.